# Reset the value of a GroupBox?

Tags: winforms, button, groupbox

So here's my problem : I want to do a Tic Tac Toe program, and I have 9 buttons and 2 progress bar (for the score)

I want that when the progress bar X or Y does a PerformStep, all the 9 buttons (in a GroupBox) resets to its initial value (`Enable = true` and `Text = " "`, because I disable it after the user clicked on it and the text changes for X or O depending of the player turn).

Is there a command that I can write for every buttons resets or I must do that one by one ?

Comment: You should already have a Button[] array in your code so you can easily check for 3-in-a-row, etcetera.  Resetting now also is trivial, just iterate the array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reset all buttons more efficiently, you could reset them in a loop.

This would require that the buttons be collected together first, for example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<Button> ticTacToeButtons = new List<Button>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ticTacToeButtons.Add(button1);
        ticTacToeButtons.Add(button2);
        ...
    }
```

Then, you can loop over them as needed:

```
    private void resetTicTacToeButtons()
    {
        foreach (Button button in ticTacToeButtons)
        {
            button.Enabled = true;
            button.Text = " ";
        }
    }
```